# File not found for min.css files in angularui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have downloaded the demo for mobileangularui. Upon loading in chrome I get error for loading mobile-angular-ui-hover.min.css, dist/css/mobile-angular-ui-base.min.css, dist/css/mobile-angular-ui-desktop.min.css and mobile-angular-ui.gestures.min.js. Am not able to understand what am I missing.

Here's my code:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/mobile-angular-ui-hover.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/mobile-angular-ui-base.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/mobile-angular-ui-desktop.min.css" />
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Required to use $touch, $swipe, $drag and $translate services -->
  <script src="dist/js/mobile-angular-ui.gestures.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you confirmed..those files are in your local drive.. under your project `/dist` folder..you need to copy those to your local drive

Comment: Yes, I checked they are present in the folder. I have copied these files in the folder parallel to /src and also tried with inside /src. However, I cannot see the minified files in when I inspect the page in chrome. For css files, it does show the folder and the files but they are blank. However, on webstorm the files have requires css styles. Am not sure where am going wrong.

Comment: Finally got this working. I needed to add the path of the less files that angular needs to less/app.less